# What are the differences between anonymous namespace and anonymous scope in c++?

Tags: c++, namespaces

What is the difference between:

```
namespace {
    // code
} // anonymous namespace
```

and

```
{
    // code
}
```

I understand that:

1. We can't write namespace inside a function
2. We can't write anonymous block outside a function
3. Anonymous namespaces have long life, they can be extended; anonymous scopes dont, everything is destroyed when it leaves the scope.

Do I miss something?

Comment: A namespace can't contain any statements, only declarations and definitions.

Comment: Frankly, the biggest similarity between the two is that both use curly braces. Pretty much everything else is different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are enormous differences.

Anything in an anonymous namespace is only visible to that compilation unit. (It's somewhat similar to one particular use of `static`). You can't put *statements* into anonymous namespaces.

`{ }` is a scoping block. It can contain *statements*.

Comment: I also know about `static` similarity. Statements - ok. So, this is it?

Comment: Another important thing, maybe good to point out, anonymous namespace is relevant to ODR, scoping block isn't.

Comment: Of course important thing, @ChrisBeck! I want to gather all the differences between this two things here. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`namespace {}` creates a namespace (a space for names) that changes how the *declarations* inside will be found *by the compiler* (in this case, it is an anonymous namespace, meaning that symbols declared inside are accessible only in the current compilation unit).

`{}` creates a scope (a block of executable code) that isolates the *statements* inside, and changes how the code within the block will be executed.

The first matters to the compiler, the second matters at execution. They are completely different things.

Answer (score 1):

There is a **big** difference: what is defined in an anonymous namespace still exists outside, although what's created inside a block dies with it ending.

Comment: Oops,I  also know that.

Comment: At this point, I start to look for similarities between the two concepts :P